# Doubt Regarding Termwise differentiation of Fourier Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Consider the following Fourier Series:
$$ x^3- \pi^2 x = 12 \sum _{ n=1}^ { \infty} \frac { (-1)^n \sin(nx)} {n^3}, x \in (- \pi,\pi) $$

> Can this Fourier Series be differentiated termwise?

The only result I know regarding termwise differentiation states that

> If $f$ is periodic with period $2l$, continuous on $\mathbb R$ and
>   $f’$ is piecewise continuous on $[-l,l]$ then the Fourier Series can
>   be differentiated termwise.

So I thought of choosing $f(x)= x^3- \pi^2 x$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$ and extend it periodically on $\mathbb  R$ but then $f$ won’t be continuous on real line and we cannot apply the result here. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the well known [theorem about differentiating sequences of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability), at least on each compact subinterval, since the sequence itself as well as the sequence of derivatives converges quite obviously uniformly on each compact subinterval of $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Edit: acutally $f$ and $f^\prime$, when extended periodically, are both continuous, so the theorem you cited does apply, as well.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on edit ? How do you see continuity of f and f’ ?

Comment: @MathLover The only points where this is not clear are $\pm \pi$, and what has to be checked is basically whether $f(\pi) = f(-\pi)$, similarly for $f^\prime$. This is just a calculation.