# For references on termwise differentiation of Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have seen a result on termwise differentiation of Fourier series:

> If$ f $ is periodic with period $ 2l $, continuous on $ \mathbb{R} $ and $ f' $ is piecewise continuous on $ [−l,l] $, then the Fourier Series of $ f $ can be differentiated termwise.

Above result is migirated from [Doubt Regarding Termwise differentiation of Fourier Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677608/doubt-regarding-termwise-differentiation-of-fourier-series/3153728#3153728)
. It is really useful to my current research. Could anyone help with reference on above result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The result in this question could be found in

> Kenneth B. Howell: Principles of Fourier Analysis, Chapman & Hall/CRC,
>   Boca Raton, Fla, 2001.